# Filtering rows in talend using a specific logic

Tags: filter, talend

I have a dataset like that in a tHashInput-component:

```
event1, event2, user
1, 1, paul
1, 2, paul
2, 1, paul
2, 2, paul
3, 3, paul
1, 1, michael
2, 1, michael
1, 1, karla
```

The events are sequential inside their columns according to the order of their occurence, meaning an event with a higher `id` happened latter. They got matched into one dataset by the `user`-column with the condition that `event2` happened after `event1`. See illustration below.

I want to filter these rows so there are no duplicates in `event1` and `event2` for the same user, and every `event1` has the closest `event2` (which hasn't been used yet for another `event1` - because no duplicates).

```
sequence for paul:

event1(1) - event1(2) - event2(1) - event2(2) - event1(3) - event2(3)

pairs:

event1(1)   event1(2)   event1(3)
event2(1)   event2(2)   event2(3)
```

So the result would look like:

```
event1, event2, user
1, 1, paul
2, 2, paul
3, 3, paul
1, 1, michael
1, 1, karla
```

(the ids are not actually the same for `event1` and `event2`, they are large integers.

I experimented with a combination of tSortRow and tUniqRow but it doesn't work.

I suppose I need some sort of loop, which iterates over `event1`, filter the row with the closest `event2`, store it in a result set and remove `event1` and its closest `event2` from the original dataset so the next `event1` filters another, the second `event2` as its closest match.

I don't know if this can be done via components or if I need java-code in a tJavaFlex e.g.

Comment: What should happen if the line 2,2,Paul is not present ? No line for event1=2 in the result ? Or a line with 2,1,Paul (even if it's used by event1=1) ?

Comment: Thanks for your question: One event1 followed by two event2 for the same user will not happen by definition. To your second question: if you have two event1 followed by 1 event2, you filter event1(1) - event2(1) (the general logic) and discard the second event1(2).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, my question is for the case where you only have 1, 1, paul / 1, 2, paul  / 2, 1, paul. What should happen then ?

Comment: okay, so the definition is that event1 has to happen before event2. That means in the case you describe Paul will have this sequence: ```event1(1) - event1(2) - event2(1)  - event2(2)``` then there will also be 2,2,Paul, it cannot happen otherwise. And then I want to keep 1,1,Paul and 2,2,Paul.